# Why is tqdm progress bar not working in a for loop containing a continue statement?

Tags: python, for-loop, continue, tqdm

So I'm using the Python `tqdm` library to display a progress bar in the terminal when I execute a Python script that includes a for loop.

For example, when I do this:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(' '*5+str(i))
```

I get this displayed in the terminal after a few seconds:

[image]

, as expected. Here the `print` statement is not important, is just a computation (I used `print` just to display the fact that the computation was done).

Now I add a `continue` statement in this way:

```
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(1)
    if i < 5:
        continue
    print(' '*5+str(i))
```

and I get this:

[image]

So, I understand that the `print` statement is skipped for each iteration below 5, but **why the progress bar is not displayed?** Is `tqdm` somehow adding a "display a progress bar" statement at the end of the loop and thus this order is been skipped like the `print` statement? I feel like it's like if `tqdm` is still storing the data of the progress bar (the one that should have been displayed), so it knows where to follow after the `continue` statement is no longer executed.

In any case **I would like to know if there is a way of having the progress bar printed in each iteration**, even with a `continue` statement inside the for loop and even if my loop won't execute `print(' '*5+str(i))` until it surpasses the fifth iteration of the loop. Just to be clear, I expect to see something like this:

[image]

Notice that this displayed the progress bar through all the iterations in the for loop but didn't add the printed number of iterations until the fifth one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of a hacky solution utilizing `bar_format`:

```
for i in tqdm(range(10), bar_format='\n{l_bar}{bar:20}{r_bar}'):
    time.sleep(1)
    if i < 5:
        continue
    print(' ' * 5 + str(i), end='', flush=True)
```

Output:

```
  0%|                    | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
 10%|██                  | 1/10 [00:01<00:09,  1.01s/it]
 20%|████                | 2/10 [00:02<00:08,  1.01s/it]
 30%|██████              | 3/10 [00:03<00:07,  1.01s/it]
 40%|████████            | 4/10 [00:04<00:06,  1.00s/it]
 50%|██████████          | 5/10 [00:05<00:05,  1.00s/it]     5
 60%|████████████        | 6/10 [00:06<00:04,  1.01s/it]     6
 70%|██████████████      | 7/10 [00:07<00:03,  1.00s/it]     7
 80%|████████████████    | 8/10 [00:08<00:02,  1.00s/it]     8
 90%|██████████████████  | 9/10 [00:09<00:01,  1.00s/it]     9
100%|████████████████████| 10/10 [00:10<00:00,  1.00s/it]
```

Note the `end=''` and `flush=True`.

Though it produces a redundant empty line at the start.

Sidenote: for `tqdm(range(10), ...)` there's a shortcut `trange`:

```
from tqdm import trange
for i in trange(10, bar_format='\n{l_bar}{bar:20}{r_bar}'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`tqdm` wants to overwrite its previous output. It does this staircase effect because your `print` is manually adding a newline when `tqdm` is not expecting that.

If you want to send out a message such that it does not interfere with the progress bar, you can use `write`, which will put your message above the progress bar.

```py
iterator = tqdm(range(10))
for i in iterator:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if i < 5:
        continue
    iterator.write(f"iteration {i}")
```

```
iteration 5
iteration 6
iteration 7
iteration 8
iteration 9
100%|████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:01<00:00,  9.20it/s]
```

Or if you want to have this behaviour of *freezing* the progress bar on its steps, you'll have to always print something afterwards, though i wouldn't really recommend this very much.

```py
for i in tqdm(range(10), ncols=60):
    time.sleep(1)
    if i < 5:
        print()
        continue
    print(' '*5+str(i))
```

```
  0%|                                | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
 10%|██▍                     | 1/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.41it/s]
 20%|████▊                   | 2/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.27it/s]
 30%|███████▏                | 3/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.23it/s]
 40%|█████████▌              | 4/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.26it/s]
 50%|████████████            | 5/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.18it/s]     5
 60%|██████████████▍         | 6/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.21it/s]     6
 70%|████████████████▊       | 7/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.21it/s]     7
 80%|███████████████████▏    | 8/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.18it/s]     8
 90%|█████████████████████▌  | 9/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.16it/s]     9
100%|███████████████████████| 10/10 [00:01<00:00,  9.20it/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a single progress bar are should be on single line, but tqdm doesn't handle other facilities writing to the console, so you get a stepped effect. As @Talon said, you can use tqdm's `write()` method which removes the progress bar, writes to the console, and redraws the progress bar.

Alternatively, you can use a different progress bar library that supports the native behavior, like [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/)

```
import time
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.Manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=10)

for i in pbar(range(10)):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(' '*5+str(i))
```